# SQLite Select records which contain url

Tags: regex, sqlite, url

I am using Sqlite.
And I have table T with three columns: ID (int), Username (Text) and Message (Text).

I need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE Message CONTAINS <URL>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

I read that Sqlite has function for handling regular expressions (regexp) but it must be implemented manually. And at this point implementing `REGEXP` is not an option.

> The `REGEXP` operator is a special syntax for the `regexp()` user function. No `regexp()` user function is defined by default and so use of the `REGEXP` operator will normally result in an error message. If an application-defined SQL function named `regexp` is added at run-time, then the `X REGEXP Y` operator will be implemented as a call to `regexp(Y,X)`.

Comment: By "not an option" you mean that you can't define `regexp()` function or you don't know how to do that? (in the latter case I'd call this "not a solution")

Answer (score 0):

try this :

**SELECT * FROM T WHERE Message LIKE '%URL%';**